# mysql_real_escape_string() not sanitizing variable

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm working on an existing website trying to prevent SQL injections. Before `$_GET['ID']` was unsanitized.

```
$ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']);
$sQuery=mysql_query("select * from tbl_mini_website as s1, tbl_actor_merchant as me where s1.MERCHANT_ID=$ID AND s1.MERCHANT_ID=me.MERCHANT_ID");
```

If I put a ' at the end of the url, with `mysql_real_escape_string()` I get this from `mysql_error()`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\' AND s1.MERCHANT_ID=me.MERCHANT_ID' at line 1

with out `mysql_real_escape_string()` I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\' AND s1.MERCHANT_ID=me.MERCHANT_ID' at line 1

I'm not sure whats up with it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you `echo` the query before perform it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is an id, numerical I assume, why don't you just cast it to an integer?

```
$ID = (int) $_GET['ID'];
```

The best advice I can give you is to [check out PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and use bound parameters.

Comment: Probably not else the orig solution would work for an integer field. I think Frank is correct to add the quotes.

Comment: @Dinah: they both correct. Frank Farmer in fact, that mysql_... doesn't add quotes, and alex - that numerics shouldn't be surrounded with quotes but used as numerics (this can cause casting/performance issues)

Answer (score 5):

mysql_real_escape_string escapes, but doesn't quote.

Try:

```
$sQuery=mysql_query("select * from tbl_mini_website as s1, tbl_actor_merchant as me where s1.MERCHANT_ID='$ID' AND s1.MERCHANT_ID=me.MERCHANT_ID");
```

More generally, I tend to wrap both of these in a function, like:

```
function quoteValue($value) {
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}
```

This is useful, because you may find down the line that you want more refined quoting behavior (especially when it comes to handling Unicode, control characters, etc.)

Comment: Thank you!! I've been working on this for an hour and it was right under my nose.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not quoting the variable.

Here's your query given the following inputs

```
$_GET['ID'] = "1";
$ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']);
SELECT ... where s1.MERCHANT_ID=1 ...

$_GET['ID'] = "1'"
$ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']);
SELECT ... where s1.MERCHANT_ID=1\' ...

$_GET['ID'] = "1'"
SELECT ... where s1.MERCHANT_ID=1' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Phil Brown is right, but you shoul forget about old fashioned `mysql_real_escape_string or mysql_connect()` as they are very old and move to php`s PDO() where you cand use prepared statements, binds, fetch object any many many more functions.

I suggest read PDO documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php if you want next generation dabatase manipulation and security from SQL Injection .